# Use a script to update a drop down

Tags: php, jquery, json

Yesterday I asked a question on this forum about how to update a HTML drop down (select-list) list depending on another drop down. Unfortunately, it was not clear for certain users. But no problem, I found out how it is working. 
So, let’s start with the script, I uploaded it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/sFhbPAFj

What is my aim?

In the first drop down (lecturer_id) I have some lecturers names and there ID’s. This information is coming from a PostgreSQL database.  As example, an option how the list could be:

X

The second list should contain the courses the lecture teaches. Another example:

Maths

This information is also coming from the database, but it should be dynamic. Like If I select teacher Y, the second list should be updates with other courses.

The problem is, I’ve no idea how I could transfer this data from my PHP application to the script above, and on the other side, I’ve no idea how I could get the lecturer_id from the jQuery script into my PHP code. (I need that ID to populate the list with the courses)

I hope my question is clear this time.

Comment: I would recommend [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for sharing code.

Answer (score 2):

best to use AJAX. Something like:

```
$("#teacher_select").change(function(){
id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "some.php/?id=" + id, // perform a query for all courses taught by this teacher and return html
              success: function(data){
                           $("#course_select").html(data);
                           }
            });
});
```

You can also return a json object and make the transition to HTML on the client-side (i.e in the `success` function), in which case don't forget to add `dataType:"json"`.

EDIT: to retrieve the courses of the first teacher on load, just use the same ajax request responding to the `onload` event - or in JQuery `$(document).ready();` - which will get you the courses of the currently selected teacher

Comment: Thanks, that's really an easy solution. I prefer to do it with json as output format. I will check how that works :-)

Comment: I got it working like it should. The only thing I can't find out is how to load it as default? I mean, now my list with courses is empty until the first dropdown is used. But, I would like to have the second list filled with courses at the start. (so, the courses of the first lecturer in the list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax function to call the database with teacher id to get the courses and update the second drop-down.

Btw user jQuery for all your javascript. insted of using `for` you can use jQuery `each`.